# Modify Shortcut Tab Between Terminals?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I currently have one terminal open with 10 tabs. How do I modify the way I move between the tabs on Ubuntu?

If you are not sure what I mean, then let me give this example. On Firefox, if I have 10 tabs open, I would press ctrl + tab to move between the tabs. On the terminal, I just checked the shortcut and it's ctrl+page down to move to the next tab. Well this is not good for me. How can I change it to ctrl+tab?

Comment: What Terminal app are you using? `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: Just the default terminal. I've got to re-phrase this question as I just realised something.

Comment: The default Terminal depends on your flavour of Ubuntu, if just the normal Ubuntu though it will be `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Try Ctrl + page up and down

Comment: Thanks, I just realised this. I need to change it to something different.

Answer (score 1):

In Gnome Terminal you can use :

- <kbd>Cntl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to move between tabs from left to right
- <kbd>Cntl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to move between tabs from right to left

**Answer to the edited question :**

To change teh key mappings for switching betwen terminals go to

```
Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts...
```

Then change it like the picture is showing :

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts_Gnome terminal]

As you can see i have changed the mappings to <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>.

Comment: How do I modify the shortcut to use ctrl+tab? In the options, it doesn't seem to like me changing it to something more than 1 button. So when I change it to, lets say "p". The I can use p to move right onto the next tab. But when I click the option and try to change it to a new accelerator (that's what it says when you click to change the shortcut), it doesn't allow me to press ctrl with tab.

Comment: @johnsmith check my edits ..also dont change your question on the fly..its totakkt diffferent from the initial question now..

Comment: My initial question hasn't changed. I modified it about 60 seconds after I created it as the question was wrong. 

Anyways, I still can't use ctrl+tab to move between my tabs. It's like the settings won't allow me to do such a binding. For now I've just bound it to ctrl+1, since that's as close to ctrl+tab as I can get and make it work.

Comment: @johnsmith Seems so..i cant do that too..